# Monitor blinks multiple times before successful booting

Tags: boot, graphics-card, hardware-failure

Monitor blinks/flickers 1 to 7 times before booting successfully. Entering the BIOS settings after pressing DEL triggers this again.

I have tested every component individually in another system and they worked fine. Clearing BIOS settings and reseeding everything did not help either.

System configuration:

- Asrock A320M HDV R4.0
- Ryzen 5 1400
- GTX 1050 ti
- 2 x 8 GB DDR4

Comment: Try updating BIOS, Video Driver and Chipset if Laptop. See if that helps. I get regular updates of these drivers from Lenovo.

Comment: It *appears* the PC is trying different graphic settings, as if identifying the display device for the first time. If you've already updated video drivers, and used DISM and SFC to perform OS repairs, then you might reinstall Windows from ISO... if you consider it worth that effort to avoid that flicker.

Comment: @John this happens at boot during BIOS. how could an OS driver (video or chipset) make any difference here?

Comment: @LPChip, some of the flickering appeared to be *after* Windows has started up.

Comment: I suggested updating BIOS to see if that helps with starting in BIOS

Comment: BIOS was up to date. So I downgraded it to a previous version. It is now constantly booting only after a single blink. I'll take it as a win. Thanks everyone